# Conditional inclusion in ssh_config

Tags: ssh, openssh, ssh-config

According to `ssh_config(5)` an `Include` statement can be placed inside a `Match` or `Host` block to create conditionsl inclusion

> **Include:** Include the specified configuration file(s). Multiple pathnames may be specified and each pathname may contain `glob(7)` wildcards and, for user configurations, shell-like `~` references to user home directories. Wildcards will be expanded and processed in lexical order. Files without absolute paths are assumed to be in `~/.ssh` if included in a user configuration file or `/etc/ssh` if included from the system configuration file. *Include directive may appear inside a Match or Host block to perform **conditional inclusion**.*

I tried to make this work, but it seems that each included file is always read, disregarding a match is found. What is going on?

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021

$ cat config_1
Match user foo
  Include config_2
Match user bar
  Include config_2
Match user !foo,!bar
  Hostname xyz

$ cat config_2
Hostname uvw

$ ssh -vv -G -F config_1 bar@random | grep '^hostname'
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data config_1
debug2: checking match for 'user foo' host random originally random
debug2: match not found
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config_2                    << unmatched include
debug2: checking match for 'user bar' host random originally random
debug2: match found
debug1: Reading configuration data ~/.ssh/config_2                    << matched include
debug2: checking match for 'user !foo,!bar' host uvw originally random
debug2: match not found
hostname uvw
```

Comment: Reading the files is always allowed... but it should not change the final configuration (given that it did not match). Do you actually get wrong results?

Comment: If you add one more -v it should say `(parse only)` for these files.

Comment: @frostschutz You are correct, In the somewhat more elaborate case, I had multiple match-blocks in there with `exec` statements. I was hoping that these executions would be avoided, but the parser still executes. Them, nonetheless, you are 100% correct, the third verbose level gives `(parse only)` and the end result is correct.

Comment: I can see how that might be annoying in some cases. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way around it. I read into the source code a little and it only skips exec if another condition on the same Match line already failed — which is weird too within the context of parse everything, execute everything, to help detect configuration errors early? In the end you'll have to ask openssh project about their intentions, I can only guess.